# Why does Emacs local-set-key not overwrite a globally set key in mode hook?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

In Emacs' `tide-mode` (typescript development) I would like to use M-q, which is normally bound to `fill-paragraph`, to rather run `tide-format`. I have a mode hook like

```
(defun setup-tide-mode ()
...
  (local-set-key [M-q] 'tide-format)
  (describe-key [M-q]))
(add-hook 'typescript-mode-hook #'setup-tide-mode)
```

When I open a typescript file I do see the `*Help*` buffer which indeed shows

```
<M-q> runs the command tide-format ...
```

Yet when I then run `C-h k M-q` to describe the key binding of M-q, I get

```
M-q runs the command fill-paragraph
```

There is this suspicious difference in the printout between `<M-q>` and `M-q`. This is probably telling me something, but I don't know what.

What would be the correct way to locally overwrite `M-q` to run a different command?

Comment: For others who read this question, `setup-tide-mode` is a poorly named variable in the [`tide`](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/tide/) package which should probably be called `tide-mode-hook`.

Comment: "...when I then run C-h k M-q to describe the key binding of M-q, I get `M-q` runs the command fill-paragraph" -- which description you can then plug verbatim into `kbd` like so: `(local-set-key (kbd "M-q") 'tide-format)` to get the key sequence you wanted.  Ask Emacs, and pass the response to `kbd`, and you can avoid all such confusions.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `[?\M-q]` instead of `[M-q]` because `?\M-q` is the event generated when you press the Alt/Meta modifier along with the Q key.